# Why are Scipy and Np Linalg producing different eigenvalues derived from the same matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Why are Scipy and Np Linalg producing different eigenvalues derived from the same matrix?

```
import numpy as np
newMat = np.array([[3,2],[1,0]])

np.linalg.eigvals(newMat) 
#Eigenvalues: ([ 3.56155281, -0.56155281])


from scipy.linalg import eigh

eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(newMat)
#Eigenvalues: ([-0.30277564,  3.30277564])
```

Answer (score 3):

They produce different values because you are currently:

- asking `numpy` to generate the eigenvalues of a matrix;
- asking `scipy` to generate the eigenvalues of a matrix *assuming the matrix is hermitian*.

The matrix is **not** hermitian, thus the `scipy` results are incorrect. 
You can generate similarly incorrect eigenvalues from `numpy` by using its `numpy.linalg.eigh` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
newMat = np.array([[3,2],[1,0]])

print(np.linalg.eigvals(newMat))
#Eigenvalues: ([ 3.56155281, -0.56155281])    

from scipy.linalg import eig
# eigvals, eigvecs = normalized left eigenvector if left=True. normalized right eigenvector if right=True.
print( np.real_if_close(eig(newMat)[0]))
#Eigenvalues: ([ 3.56155281 -0.56155281])
```